# Use a slider handle to drag through image slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, slider, slideshow, fade

I want my website visitors to be able to use a [jQuery slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) to 'drag' their way through a sequence of images. Only one image is shown at a time, and when the user drags the slider handle left and right, the shown image changes to the next/previous in the sequence. Additionally, and this is the tricky part, I want the new image to fade in on top of the previous image.

I have the slider code working, using the jQuery slider:

```
$( "#mySlider" ).slider({
range: "max",
min: 1,
max: 10,
value: 1,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    // CODE THAT MAKES THE NEW IMAGE FADE IN
}
});
```

Currently, my plan is to actually have all images in the HTML in separate DIVs that overlay each other and with opacity 0. Dragging the handle would put the relevant div on top and fade it in.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this (link to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aXfHL/1/))

html

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SfzW1.jpg" class="abs pic1" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/hsVyi.jpg" class="abs pic2" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RJVm9.jpg" class="abs pic3" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dw00y.jpg" class="abs pic4" />
</div>
```

and the css

```
#gallery{
    position: relative;
}

img {
    display:none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index:0;
}


.pic1{
    display:inline;
}
.abs{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

javaScript/jquery

```
$( "#mySlider" ).slider({
range: "max",
min: 1,
max: 4,
value: 1,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    var pic_num = ui.value;
    var new_image_elm = $("#gallery img.pic"+pic_num);
    var old_image_elm = $("#gallery img:visible");

    if(new_image_elm != null){
        var zIndex = parseInt(old_image_elm.css('z-index'));
        new_image_elm.css('z-index', zIndex+1);        
        new_image_elm.fadeIn( "slow", function() {
            // Animation complete
            old_image_elm.hide();
        });         
    }
}
});
```

Comment: You can also use the lt-selector and skip pic1,pic2 etc classes http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Comment: That got me halfway - the fade works when I slide to the right, but not when I slide to the left; the image changes correctly, but doesn't fade. (You can see my test at http://borishansen.dk/slider/index_fade.htm).

Comment: @BorisHansen. Ok, I updated the code and added z-index. Should be working as expected now.

Comment: This seems absolutely perfect. The only thing I note is that if I quickly drag the slider from position X to X+1 (or X-1) and back to X again, before the first fade completes, the image disappears altogether. Is this something that can be circumvented?

Comment: Yes, you can fix this by using jquerys complete function better. You are now hiding the "old element" as soon as the animation is complete, there is no gard for checking if it's the current animation.