# Implement jQuery in html

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on slideshow, which one can drag through using a slider. Since I do have very little coding experience, I use [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20403627/use-a-slider-handle-to-drag-through-image-slideshow) as basis (see code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aXfHL/1/))

Problem: I cannot make it work (yes, I am really a newbie), the slider does not appear. I guess it has something to do with importing the jQuery library. I tried different ways, as recommended in some other topics, but it didn't work out yet. So there might be another problem.

My html-code so far (the files I refer to are present in the same folder, of course):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="myslider.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myslider.js"></script>
    <div id="mySlider"></div>
    <div id="gallery">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SfzW1.jpg" class="abs pic1" />
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/hsVyi.jpg" class="abs pic2" />
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RJVm9.jpg" class="abs pic3" />
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dw00y.jpg" class="abs pic4" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any thoughts? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your console/network tab

Comment: what's in `myslider.js` please use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: What have you actually tried so far? What does your myslider.js file contain? In what way does it not work? If you want us to help you, you need to provide some details, user252375.

Comment: I copied-pasted this one: http://jsfiddle.net/aXfHL/1/

Comment: Do you have `jquery-1.11.0.js` locally?

Comment: @Zword Yes I have. The problem is that the slider does not appear, although I did not manipulate the myslider.js-file of this one: jsfiddle.net/aXfHL/1

Comment: Where is your JQuery code?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval functoin for repeating a function. Take this as an example and change the code according to your need

```
var current=1;
function showNext()
{
$("#gallery").children().hide();
$("#gallery").children().eq(current).show();
current++;
if(current==4)
{
    current=0;
}

}
setInterval(showNext,1000);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/26/)